# How to update html outside of html frame using javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is kind of complicated, so bear with me. I have a form that is inside a HTML frame. When I click the button on that form I would like to update the HTML that is outside of that frame.

I'll try to illustrate this as best I can

**Page Layout**

- Header Html Content (not in a frame)
- Side Menu Frame
- Content Menu Frame

I have some HTML in the **Header** section of the page that I would like to update when a user clicks on a form button in the **Content Menu Frame**.

The problem is I don't know how to access the HTML is the Header section from within the frame. So currently I have to hard refresh the page (ctrl + f5) for the changes to take place.

Thanks!

**Update

Using old school style frames, not iframes

Comment: You should make clear whether you're using frames (with frameset) or iFrames.  With old-style frames, what you're trying to do is possible.  (Whether it is advisable is another question.)  GSto says that it's not possible with iFrames, which wouldn't surprise me...so you might be well served by updating your question with which you're trying to use.

Comment: sorry about that. I'm using regular frames with frameset. I'd never use frames like this on my own system, but for this existing system I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one that worked.

parent.top.location.reload(true)

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

you can access the head element of the top frame via

```
window.top.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about an iFrame, javascript in an iFrame can't access the HTML in the parent of that frame, you'll have to use a hard refresh.